# How to make IDs non-sequencial?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have an entity

```
@Entity
data class Person (
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    val id: Long
)
```

But I noticed the values for `id` are consecutive. Is there a way to let Spring Boot make them more random?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom identifier generator and use it.

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "seq", 
        strategy = "com.java.generators.SequenceIdGenerator", 
        parameters = {...})
    private String id;

    ...
}
```

Here you should create `com.java.generators.SequenceIdGenerator` by own

A good tutorial about [this](https://thorben-janssen.com/custom-sequence-based-idgenerator/)